# Load cell accuracy: rated output vs. full scale

Tags: datasheet, load-cell, accuracy

I'm currently shopping for some subminature load cells for a research project. I've narrowed it down to two options, the FUTEK [LCM100](http://www.futek.com/files/pdf/Product%20Drawings/lcm100.pdf) and the Burster [Model 8417](https://www.burster.com/fileadmin/user_upload/redaktion/Documents/Products/Data-Sheets/Section_8/8417_EN.pdf). Problem is the two specify their accuracy in a different manner.

Futek gives the standard Nonlinearity, Repeatability, Hysteresis values but as a % of *rated output*:

- **Nonlinearity:** ±0.5 % of R.O.
- **Hysteresis:** ±0.5 % of R.O.
- **Nonrepeatability:** ±0.1 % of R.O.

Whereas the Burster gives a single value as a combined % of *full scale*:

- **Combined value consisting of non-linearity, hysteresis and nonrepeatability,
  in installation position:** < ±0.9 % of F.S.

The rep from the Burster reseller says his are more accurate by **1.1%**, but from what I can see the FUTEK cells are more accurate. Am I missing something here? Are rated output and full scale synonymous in this context or is there an important difference? Does "combined" mean a sum of all of the accuracy percentages or an average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rated output and full scale are intended to mean roughly the same things here.

There's not a lot to choose between the two devices in terms of accuracy, both have 'about 1%' total error, and esssentially the same temperture coefficient.

There are a couple of differences.

Overload
Futek gives a safe overload of 150%. Burster indicates that a static 100% is safe, static 200% is an overload, and says 70% is the maximum for using it dynamically, recommended 50%. So you can't compare apples directly with apples here. With dynamic loading, you might want to contact the manufacturers to find out exactly what their test conditions and their failure criteria are.

Stiffness aka deflection
There's an order of magnitude difference here, the Futek is stiffer and specifies a resonant frequency, will that matter to you?

Comment: I *think* the Burster datasheet is using a percentage per 50 Kelvin, and the FUTEK is using per 1 Kelvin (or per degree C as they put it). So dividing the Burster data by 50 gives a marginally worse value than the FUTEK, 0.05 per Kelvin vs. 0.036 per Kelvin. So not a factor of two, but still better. It does looke like the rep was incorrect.

Comment: @Crazymoomin doh! 'd caught the 50 bit, but I didn't spot the Futek figure was in furlongs, or fahrenheit or whatever, that's the factor of 2!

Comment: Yeah, FUTEK is based in the USA, Burster is German hence the freedom units (though I'd argue specifying temperature coefficients in per 50 Kelvin isn't the best either). Interestingly their sub 1 pound-force models all use gram-force.